# Using the GData API, is there a way to authorize an application access to a single Google Doc Spreadsheet?

Tags: gdata

I'd like to read and write data to a published Google spreadsheet via the GDATA API, but I don't want my app to be authenticated with full Spreadsheet authorization (giving it full access to that user's docs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible according to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20).

The documentation does not indicate if it is possible to restrict the scope of authentication OAuth2 : `http(s)://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/`.